# home page generated by pkgdown not rendering properly

Tags: r, pkgdown

After a few months without updating my package mRpostman, I decided to include GitHub Actions unit test badge on README.Rmd file. I used `usethis::use_github_action("check-standard")` then manually added the URL to the badge as recommended. I have also updated pkgdown version to the newest one (2.0.7) as of July 2023. The package web site renders smoothly locally. Nonetheless, when pushing the changes to github, the package's home page does not render properly. The logo is oversized to be more precise. The only warning message I get when running `pkgdown::build_site()` is:

```
Warning message:
Failed to parse example for topic 'ImapCon'
```

Nonetheless, nothing has changed in terms of code or documentation. I believe this warning was also present in the previous version. Even so, the page is rendered without any problems locally.

Things I have tried so far without any success:

1. resizing the figure by manually adjusting the width in the  HTML tag on README.Rmd;
2. I have also tried `pkgdown::clean_site()`, but that did not solve the problem.

Info to replicate the problem:

1. The URL to the website is http://allanvc.github.io/mRpostman
2. The source code is available at https://github.com/allanvc/mRpostman/

Here is how the page looks (locally vs. published):

**Local:**

[image: Local]

**Published:**

[image: Published]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of days, the only thing that solved the problem was downgrading pkgdown to the version I had before things got broken.
Now, the package home page renders smoothly with pkdown version 1.6.1.

Comment: I just encountered a similar issue where the web site renders locally but after pushing to GitHub, the page didn't render correctly. Downgrading to a an older version of `pkgdown` solved the issue for me as well.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem. I deleted all the cache in my Github actions which fixed the issue.